# Help - I lost my password

Tags: logical-deduction, password

I lost my password to a critical website. All I have is a really obfuscating password hint. Can you please help me figure it out?

My password hint:

> Third letter is r, middle is a.

In my email I found the process I used to make the password:

> Set the Table
>   That holds all things
>   Find the two most important places
>   To the right of the bottom one
>   Take the first three letters. Keep the capitalization intact.
>   Now add the first two letters of her first name. Capitalization intact.
>   Take away 49. Add the symbol. All caps.
>   Add two and take the square root. Use the other number of it rounded to the nearest whole number.
>   Now place the number between the doubled letters.
>   You're set!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

> **CurMa14AG**

Set the Table
That holds all things

> The Periodic Table of Elements

Find the two most important places
To the right of the bottom one

> Wasn't really sure what this means specifically, but combined with the password hint and the logic of the next line, I made an assumption and went with it. It may have something to do with which version is being referenced.

Take the first three letters. Keep the capitalization intact. Now add the first two letters of her first name. Capitalization intact.

> The only thing that makes sense here (and just so happens to fit the hint) is **Curium** (*Cm*), named after Pierre and **Marie**.  So, we get **CurMa**. "r" is the 3rd letter, and we have an "a", so there are probably only 4 characters after this.

Take away 49. Add the symbol. All caps.

> Chemical number of *Cm* is 96. Take away 49, and you have 47, the chemical number for Silver (*Ag*) -> All caps -> **AG**.   We have **CurMaAG**.

Add two and take the square root. Use the other number of it rounded to the nearest whole number. Now place the number between the doubled letters.

> Add two to 47 yields 49, and taking the square root yields 7. Nitrogen (*N*) has atomic number 7. The "other number for it" might refer to the Standard atomic weight of Nitrogen, which is 14.007. Rounded to the nearest whole number yields 14. Place between the doubled letters, and we get **CurMa14AG**. Voila!

Comment: Take away 49 instead of 46, and you'll be quite, quite close.

Comment: Wow, for a second there I was like, "Can I not read?!?!" Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Cu is Copper (Cuprum)

Comment: @question_asker Derp, thanks.  Just went ahead and wrote it out without referencing back.

Comment: @feelinferrety No problem! I had to check myself, because for all I knew, there was a reshuffling of chemical symbols since the last time I used the periodic table. Also, duh, I didn't realize that doesn't change the actual password, oops.

Comment: So, what are the "two most important places"?

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but... @Gamow, thanks for the help in getting to the final solution but in the future, can you please either add a comment with your ideas or submit your own answer instead of making significant edits that completely change the existing answer?